# Merging by Char

Tags: r, merge

I need to merge 2 datasets.
In the first dataset I have my observations containing all data collected, of which one is a Code for a diagnosis (ICD). To make the analytics easier I would like to add the second dataset, which shows all codes with the fitting diagnose and a group name. One of the codes from df2 could easily be needed for multiple observations in df1.
I have tried merging the two datasets with merge(), but it is not working. There is no error message, but the tables end up being empty or it adds one table on top of the other, so I have the double amout of observations but no extra variable.

This is the codeline I am using and some example lines (shortend for only the necessary data).

```
head(df1)
Overall_ID   ICD     age     .....
  1862       Q85.9   70
  1863       K57     63
  1864       K57     48
  1865       R33     24
  1866       T14     50

head(df2)
ICD      subgroup
K57      disease of intestines
K58      disease of intestines
Q85.9    phakomatosis
R33      urinary retention
T14      NA

df1_df2 < merge(df1, df2, by = "ICD", all = TRUE)
```

I have made sure that I have a variable in both datasets calles "ICD" to actually merge by.

Is there something in the datasets that could prevent merging?
Is there another way to try to add the datasets together?

Comment: Provide example data. `dput(head(df1))` and `dput(head(df2))`

Comment: `merge` will never *"add one table on top of the other"*, but *"double amout [sic] of observations"* sounds like you have multiple matches, which is a common "feature" (when desired) and mis-understanding of merges/joins. Please add sample data (only rows/columns we *need*, no more, and please make sure there are relevant matches and perhaps some no-matches) and your expected output given that sample data.

Comment: `merge` will add one table on top of the other if you have **no matches**, perhaps due to whitespace or other differences in your ICD column. All the same, we can't diagnose the problem without sample data.

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand correctly, you want to add a column named `subgroup` (like in df2) to your df1 - while matching the values from `df2$subgroup` via the `ICD` column.

```
require("dplyr")

combined_df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "ICD")

# Or use the pipe:
combined_df <- df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = "ICD")

# Or use the base pipe(Only R >= 4.1.0) :
combined_df <- df1 |> left_join(df2, by = "ICD")
```

Done.

Comment: Hi y3MyRon, thank you! This has solved the problem that my data doubles, but the subgroup variable is still all "NA". Could there be a problem with the data, that the two rows dont match?

Comment: Hi @Shnetti, if you reconstruct the frames as seen above, the join doesn't create any NAs - so its very likly that its something about your data.
First: Try `names(df1)` and `names(df2)` to see if the column names really are what you expect.

Second: If the names are both the same (ICD) then try `class(df1$ICD)`, `class(df2$ICD)` and `typeof(df1$ICD)` and `typeof(df2$ICD)` to check if there are some fundamental differences.

Besides that, its hard to solve your issue without any further examples.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be white space, loading the data with `strip.white = TRUE` solved the issue and let me merge the data.